# how to replace text in input field with Capybara

Tags: capybara

For my integration test of editing a record, I try to replace the existing text in a form input field with a new text:

```
find("input[@id='course_title']").set("a safer workplace")
```

However,everytime I check the page with

```
save_and_open_page
```

the text in the input field is not replaced with the new test.

how can I replace the text value of an input field a new text value in Capybara?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, try one of these:

```
fill_in('course_title', :with => 'a safer workplace')
find("input#course_title]").set("a safer workplace")
find(:xpath, "//input[@id='course_title']").set("a safer workplace")
```

Comment: I had to first say `fill_in('some_name', :with => '')` to make it work.

Comment: The above works!  It's the answer to this question!  But it looks inelegant.  Is it possible to do this using 1 line, instead of 2?

Comment: `find("input#course_title]").set("").set("a safer workplace")` should work as a 1 liner

Comment: Suddenly my test broke again and text was apending instead of replacing, but I had to change clearing command from set("") to set(" ") to make it work again